# Javascript : total length of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object like this :

```
MyObject { 
  Object1: ["12345", "67890"]
  Object2: ["74185"]
  Object3: ["29630", "789654"]
}
```

I need to get the total number of elements. In this exemple , I should get 5. I'm trying to do this in the most efficient way.

Comment: An object does not have a length. If you want to sum the lengths of its array-valued elements, then do so explicitly. Just write a simple loop.

Comment: Does all objects have this structure or you want something that can generically count every objects in an object graph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `for` loop to loop through the object, checking to ensure the key is an Array before incrementing a length counter:

```
var count = 0;

for (var key in MyObject)
  if (MyObject[key] instanceof Array)
    count += MyObject[key].length;
```

```js
var MyObject = { 
  Object1: ["12345", "67890"],
  Object2: ["74185"],
  Object3: ["29630", "789654"]
}

var count = 0;

for (var key in MyObject)
  if (MyObject[key] instanceof Array)
    count += MyObject[key].length;

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` for everything!

```
var totalLength = Object.keys(MyObject).reduce(function(total, key) {
    return total += MyObject[key].length;
}, 0);
```

Comment: You'll want to `return total + MyObject[key].length;` for simplicity

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to iterate over all keys of the map and sum the length of every array.

Functional way to do this:

```
function add(a, b) { return a + b; }

Object.keys(test).map(function(key) {
  return test[key].length
}).reduce(add);
```

Or if you're on one of the latter Node.js versions:

```
Object.keys(test).map(key => test[key].length).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
```

Comment: @Arg0n: OP asked for the most efficient way, which this answer certainly describes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `for in` loop to iterate all the objects and add the counts by find the length of the array.

While using `for in` its is recommended to use `hasOwnProperty()` to avoid unnecessory properties being iterated due to prototypical inheritance.

```
var count = 0;
for (var key in MyObject) {
    if (MyObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        count += MyObject[key].length;
    }
}
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following code:

- Use `Object.keys()` to "loop" on your object properties.
- Use property `length` of each `array` to know how many items are in the array.
- Increment variable `count` accordingly.

Please note, your `MyObject` was malformed because:

- There is and assignment operator (=).
- Missing comma (,) after each properties.
- No use of var (I am assuming you do not want MyObject as global object).

```js
var myObject =  {
  Object1: ["12345", "67890"],
  Object2: ["74185"],
  Object3: ["29630", "789654"]
};

var count = 0;
Object.keys(myObject).map(function(prop) {
    count+= myObject[prop].length;
});
alert(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party but for completeness here is my approach using [ES2019](https://262.ecma-international.org/10.0/#sec-array.prototype.flat) introduced method [`<Array>.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). First you can get all arrays with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and then `flat()` to merge all arrays together in order to get the total length.

Since the `flat()`-method only flattens one *layer* at a time per default you can pass `2` as an argument (depth).

In terms of code length this is the most efficient way to solve your problem I've seen so far.

```js
const myobject = {
  Object1: ["12345", "67890"],
  Object2: ["74185"],
  Object3: ["29630", "789654"],
};

console.log(Object.values(myobject).flat(2).length);
```

In case `myobject` has nested arrays you can also go with [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity). Just to be sure ;)

```js
const myobject = {
  Object1: [
    "1",
    "2",
    [
      ["3", "4"],
      ["5", "6"],
    ],
  ],
  Object2: ["7"],
  Object3: ["8", "9"],
};

console.log(Object.values(myobject).flat(Infinity).length);
```